# QGIS Crashes on USB/Storage device Plug-in/out

Tags: qgis, qgis-3

I am using QGIS Version 3.4.0-madeira on Windows 10, and my QGIS crashes each time, a USB device is plugged in/plugged out, or even any network drive gets disconnected with while running QGIS. This only happens when QGIS is open, and a storage drive is connected.

It also makes my QGIS Slow, when the network is busy while copying to network drive or USB.

I read it on QGIS Forum, that this is a bug in the QGIS 3.4. How can I fix this issue ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upgrade to 3.4.3 -- the bug was fixed in a patch release.